# How to have equations with captions, while they are not listed as figures, but as equations?

Tags: equations

Actually, I want to have the same functionality for equations as for figures: captions, text floating around equations (wrapfigure), List of equations in toc.

How to do?
The usual way is to press equations into the figure environment, like here:

[equation number to caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216029/equation-number-to-caption)

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could define a new equation environment as described in [Referencing equation counter value in custom float caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97029/referencing-equation-counter-value-in-custom-float-caption)